# Value assigned to type member via method type parameter breaks type equivalence

Tags: scala, type-parameter, type-members, type-equivalence

Why does the following type equivalence hold

```
trait Foo { type T }
val fa = new Foo { type T = Int }

implicitly[fa.T =:= Int] // OK
```

but when type member `T` is assigned via method parameter `A` then type equivalence does not hold

```
def makeFoo[A]: Foo = new Foo { type T = A }
val fb = makeFoo[Int]

implicitly[fb.T =:= Int] // ERROR
```

Intuitively I would expect if `T = A` and `A = Int` then `T = Int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the return type of `makeFoo` is only `Foo` and not `Foo { type T = A }`. If you don't explicitly declare it or if you refine it, the error will go away.

```
def makeFoo[A] = new Foo { type T = A }
val fb = makeFoo[Int]

implicitly[fb.T =:= Int] // No more error

or

def makeFoo2[A]: Foo { type T = A } = new Foo { type T = A }
val fc: Foo { type T = Int } = makeFoo[Int]

implicitly[fc.T =:= Int] // No more error
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/knIfPcXqSQKXXCXJ2teHkg):

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/knIfPcXqSQKXXCXJ2teHkg.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add that possibility to specify not the precise return type but its supertype (an upper bound) is called whiteboxity.

In Scala 2 this can be achieved with [whitebox macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

def makeFoo[A]: Foo = macro impl[A]
def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"new Foo { type T = ${weakTypeOf[A]} }"
}

val fb = makeFoo[Int]
implicitly[fb.T =:= Int] //compiles
```

In Dotty this can be achieved with keyword `transparent` ([currently](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html#transparent-inline-methods))

```
transparent inline def makeFoo[A]: Foo = new Foo { type T = A }
val fb = makeFoo[Int]
summon[fb.T =:= Int] //compiles
```

Former syntax is

```
inline def makeFoo[A] <: Foo = new Foo { type T = A }
```